# Problema con Package Manager en Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Estoy desarrollando una app en Xamarin Forms, y el xamarin.droid tengo el siguiente método para validar si la app whatsapp ('com.whatsapp') esta instalada (cosa que en el dispositivo físico de prueba esta instalada) y siempre me arroja la excepción NameNotFoundException:

```
 public bool AppInstalledOrNot(string uri)
    {
        PackageManager pm = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager; //revision de todas las app instaladas en el dispositivo
        // ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(uri, PackageInfoFlags.Activities);
        try
        {
            if (pm == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                pm.GetPackageInfo(uri, PackageInfoFlags.SigningCertificates);
                return true;
            }
            
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

y la excepción arrojada es la siguiente:

> 

{Android.Content.PM.PackageManager+NameNotFoundException: com.whatsapp\n  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in :0 \n  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in :0 \n  at Android.Content.PM.PackageManagerInvoker.GetPackageInfo (System.String packageName, Android.Content.PM.PackageInfoFlags flags) [0x00032] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-30/mcw/Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.cs:5690 \n  at AppRichGP.Droid.Class.WhatsAppIntentAndroid.AppInstalledOrNot (System.String uri) [0x0000d] in J:\AppRichGP\AppRichGP\AppRichGP.Android\Class\WhatsAppIntentAndroid.cs:19 \n  --- End of managed Android.Content.PM.PackageManager+NameNotFoundException stack trace ---\nandroid.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.whatsapp\n\tat android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:283)\n\tat android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:255)\n\tat crc64ee486da937c010f4.ButtonRenderer.n_onClick(Native Method)\n\tat crc64ee486da937c010f4.ButtonRenderer.onClick(ButtonRenderer.java:104)\n\tat android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)\n\tat android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222)\n\tat android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)\n\tat android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)\n\tat android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)\n\tat android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)\n\tat android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)\n\tat android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)\n\tat com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)\n\tat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)\n}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mètodo deberìa solo obtener la informaciòn de `PackageManager` y verificar si existe un nombre de paquete igual a "com.whatsapp", realizalo de esta forma:

```
public bool AppInstalledOrNot(string paquete)
    {
      try 
       {
        bool isInstalled = false;
        PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)) {
           if (packageInfo.packageName.equals(paquete)) {
              isInstalled = true;
              break;
           }
        }
      } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) 
      {
          isInstalled = false;
      }
        return isInstalled;
    }
```

llamarìas el mètodo de esta forma:

```
bool whatsappInstalado = AppInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp");
```

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys funciona

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te arroja la excepción porque no encuentra el paquete, puedes probar de esta manera:

```
private bool AppInstalledOrNot(string packageName) 
{
  bool installed = false;
  PackageManager packageManager = this.PackageManager;
  try 
  {
    packageManager.GetPackageInfo(packageName, PackageInfoFlags.Activities);
    installed = true;
  } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) 
  {
    installed = false;
  }

  return installed;
}
```

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask